# Problemas com ScriptResource.axd e ASP.NET versão 4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Anteriormente meu projeto era do tipo WebForms e utilizava a versão 3.5 do .NET Framework. Porém o converti para Web Application e atualizei o framework para 4.5 e algumas funcionalidades que antes não apresentavam problemas simplesmente não existem mais.

Exemplo:
Tenho os botões Salvar e Cancelar dentro de um ContentTemplate que está dentro de um UpdatePanel que está dentro de uma div com id #divParametro2. O elemento div#divParametro2 é "do tipo jQuery Dialog".

Depois da conversão, quando coloco um breakpoint nos eventos 'click' dos botões Salvar e Cancelar, e clico nestes botões, nada acontece. Literalmente nada! Nenhum erro javascript e o debug não pára nos breakpoints criados.

A imagem abaixo é da caixa de ferramentas do navegador após a página ter sido carregada.

[image: Caixa de Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor - Google Chrome]

Pesquisei na internet sobre o arquivo ScriptResource.axd, mas só entendi que ele gerencia requisições assíncronas. Não sei como utilizá-lo ou desabilitá-lo.

A segunda linha de erro, do arquivo jquery-1.4.4-min.js, linha 23, acredito que explique o motivo de alguns popups dentro do popup principal, que contém os botões de ação Salvar e Cancelar não abrirem. :'(

Preciso de uma direção.

Comment: está usando o dialog do jQueryUI? se sim está movendo o dialog para dentro do form após abri-lo?

Comment: Olhei o código fonte e sim, o Dialog é filho de um elemento form, mas parece ter sido posto lá dinamicamente, preciso confirmar isto.